# Best way to export a Python sqlite table to .csv file

Tags: python, sqlite, csv

I have a simple single table in Python 2.7 sqllite. I just want to port the table to a external .csv file.

Been reading a few tutorials and they are writing gobs and gobs of code to do this.

Seems like this would be a simple method to call up the table ('Select * FROM Table') and save it to .csv.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried just using the sqlite shell? It has a csv output mode.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the csv module for output, especially if your string fields contain commas.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('example_database')

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('drop table example_table')
cursor.execute('create table example_table(string varchar(10), number int)')
cursor.execute('insert into example_table (string, number) values(?, ?)', ('hello', 10))
cursor.execute('insert into example_table (string, number) values(?, ?)', ('goodbye', 20))
cursor.close()

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from example_table')
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print('{},{}'.format(row[0], row[1]))
cursor.close()

connection.close()
```